# Is there an Android Layout that can be set to automatically wrap "exceding" elements to the next line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

In an Android app, I am trying to dynamically populate a TableLayout from an array, and I want each TableRow to hold at maximum 3 elements.

The way I had to implement it (code below), feels a lot like dynamically creating HTML tables and I was wondering if Android had more ad-hoc layout facilities that don't make me feel as if I am forcing my *design idea* over a more generic Layout like TableLayout.

Ideally, I would just like to deal with a layout that:

- is aware of the number of elements I want per row (maybe via configuration?),
- automatically stacks the TextViews horizontally, wrapping them on the next row only if they fill up the previous, so that I could simply cycle through the array elements and do `myLayout.add(TextView)`.

Do we have something like that, or there's no other better way than handcrafting it?

In the latter case, how would you've done that?

```
TableLayout tab_lay = (TableLayout) viewRef.findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

TableRow table_row = new TableRow(contextRef);

int col_counter = 0;
for (TextView aTextView : arrayOfTextViews) {

    table_row.addView(aTextView);
    col_counter++;

    if (col_counter == 3) {
        tab_lay.addView(table_row);
        table_row = new TableRow(contextRef);
        col_counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridLayout vs TableLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300540/gridlayout-vs-tablelayout)

Comment: Just because that question is related to the concept of table layout and its children elements it does not mean it covers what I am specifically asking here, in fact it doesn't, both neither in the question itself and the answes. Hence I don't see how you could mark this a duplicate.

Comment: These are the only table layouts provided by the platform, unless you count `GridView`, which is a scrollable adapter-based dynamic container similar to `ListView`. Therefore I linked to a comparison between them. As hinted at in the answer, `GridLayout` has more automatic management, although it doesn't allow pre-defining the number of elements per row or column. Feel free to explore the documentation related to them.

Comment: Well are you sure that there is no way to do what I am trying to do? You're not just linking another question, you're marking my question as a duplicate, only based on the assumption that a different question could imply an answer to mine just because it is a broader question. First this hasn't explicitly happened yet, second even if it does, that wouldn't automatically make my question into a duplicate. The rationale and context might make a difference and lead to very diverse answers and advised paths.

Comment: There is no layout that can be pre-configured with variable number of columns or rows. This can be very easily investigated and confirmed by looking though the various layouts. My linked question _does_ address your second point though, in the "cells do not normally overlap in a GridLayout" quote from the documentation. Also, note that you're encouraged to do your own research before posting questions, and since you didn't even mention `GridLayout` it doesn't look like you did much of it.

Comment: I know about GridLayout but Android API is always changing and not always thoroughly documented and also I didn't mention it because I didn't want the possible answers to focus just on this or that Layout type only. Instead I wanted to keep it open and see what it could be possible to come up with. I've only mentioned TableLayout because that's what I used for building a quick functioning example which had the purpose of illustrating a typical layout situation, in order to be able to ask for information on a broader level.